# Wordpress only first post different design

Tags: html, wordpress, loops, post, content-management-system

I have a blog(offline making) and I have Made a wordpress loop it checks if the First post it it uses different style and rest of other posts uses different.

Problem is: It works fine but when I go to next page(2) it shows again, I only want to apply for only First latest post. Not for First post on every page.

Code:

```
    <?php 
         while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
             <?php $count++; ?>
                   <?php if ($count == 1 && is_home()) : 

                      //First post different style goes here

                   <?php else : ?>

                      //Rest Other post different style goes here 

            <?php endif; ?>
          <?php
       endwhile;
    ?>

<?php else : ?>

     <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
           <header class="entry-header">
               <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
           </header><!-- .entry-header -->

           <div class="page_content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
           </div><!-- .entry-content -->
      </article><!-- #post-0 -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `get_query_var('paged')`. It will return the current page number, starting from 0.

So you should add

```
<?php if ($count == 1 && is_home() && get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) : ?>
    //First post different style goes here
<?php else : ?>
    //Rest Other post different style goes here 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Add this to your function.php to change the number of posts

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );
function custom_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ( is_home() && get_query_var( 'paged' ) > 0 ) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 12);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanx Mate it worked @Stanimir Stoyanov, Also How can I balance the number of posts for each page, as of now its set to 13 from wordpress reading section. 
When I go to second page the number of posts are not accurate its missing one at end.

Comment: As far as I understand you want equal number of posts for each blog page, right?
You should create custom query, skipping the posts_per_page set in Reading settings.

Comment: Yes Thats right, on Home page First post is Slider and total posts are 13 where in on second page its simple basic 3 grids posts. For second page we skip slider so there is extra one post on second page. For an e.g: building something this style posts https://templated.co/ check first and second page

Comment: Can you help me with this ?

Comment: You should change the number of posts when you are on second, third etc page to 12 right? I have added additional code to my comment which you can use.

Comment: Appreciate your help, Thanx mate